# Can I use the same keystore in different systems?

Tags: android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

I am building an application and I also have the keystore for it. But, now I have to change my laptop and run the application on the new laptop so can I use the same keystore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use the same keystore.

If your application code is the same and the location it reads the keystore from is the same, you can basically replicate your application on your new workstation exactly like your old workstation.